# Is this the best way to iterate over 2 singly linked lists of different size and a static array?

Tags: c++, arrays, list, c++11

I'm trying to use only C++11 standard code and I have 2 structs like this:

```
struct ExampleObject{
    string name;
    int somethingElse;
};
struct Node{
    ExampleObject exampleObject;
    Node* next;
};
```

And also 2 singly linked lists of type Node objects (pointed by "head1" and "head2"), sorted in ascendent order by "name".

Now I want to merge those two lists into a static array (knowing that there will never be more than 1000 elements in both lists), still sorted by name. The thing is, I don't know beforehand how many elements the lists have and they might not be of the same size.
I thought of something like this: start iterating over the lists, node by node and comparing them to find the lesser value and inserting it into the array. As soon as one of the lists reaches its end, I continue iterating over the other one, inserting each element in the array.

This is my code, but I feel it has many duplicate instructions and that maybe there's a better way to work it out:

```
ExampleObject staticArray[1000];
int i=0;
while ((i!=1000) and (head1!=nullptr) and (head2!=nullptr)){
    if (head1->exampleObject.name < head2->exampleObject.name){
        staticArray[i]=head1->exampleObject;
        head1=head1->next;
    }
    else{
        staticArray[i]=head2->exampleObject;
        head2=head2->next;
    }
    i++;
}
if (head1==nullptr)
    while ((head2!=nullptr) and (i!=1000)){
        staticArray[i]=head2->exampleObject;
        head2=head2->next;
        i++;
    }
else
    if (head2==nullptr)
        while ((head1!=nullptr) and (i!=1000)){
            staticArray[i]=head1->exampleObject;
            head1=head1->next;
            i++;
        }
```

Is there a better way to re-write these instructions into a more "condensed" way to tidy it up a bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you *need* to write your own linked list or can you use `std::list`?

Comment: Yes, I need to use that exact data structure.

Comment: You need to look at [`merge algorithms`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

Write a forward iterator.

```
struct myit{
  Node* ptr=0;
  using value_type=ExampleObject;
  using reference=value_type&;
  using pointer=value_type*;
  using iterator_tag=std::forward_iterator_tag;
  using difference=std::ptrdiff_t;
  reference operator*()const{ return ptr->exampleObject;}
  pointer operator->()const{ return &ptr->exampleObject;}
  myit& operator++(){
    ptr=ptr->next;
    return *this;
  }
  myit operator++(int){
    myit r=*this;
    ++*this;
    return r;
  }
  friend bool operator==(myit lhs, myit rhs){ return lhs.ptr==rhs.ptr; }
  friend bool operator!=(myit lhs, myit rhs){ return lhs.ptr!=rhs.ptr; }
};
```

I think that is it; I may have missed some operations or have typos.  There are many guides online including on SO.

Once you have this, we are golden.  Just use the `std` algorithm that merges to an iterator.

It is called `std::merge`:

```
std::array<ExampleObject,1000> buffer;
auto order= [](ExampleObject const& lhs, ExampleObject const& rhs)->bool{
  return lhs.name<rhs.name;
};
std::merge( myit{head_a}, myit(), myit{head_b}, myit(), buffer.begin(), order);
```

And done.

Ths point of this is that it is easier to write the iterator wrapper and confirm it is valid than to do the same to merge code.

Hmm, I used a C++14 feature.  In C++11 you will need to add:

```
myit(Node*p):ptr(p){}
myit()=default;
myit(myit const&)=default;
myit& operator=(myit const&)=default;
```

because C++11 doesn't like using `{}` style init implicitly when we default `ptr=0`.  Price of using an old standard.

I also used `std::array`.  If you must use a C-style array, just pass it by name instead of `buffer.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of the last `if`/`else`.

The following code

```
if (head1==nullptr)
    while ((head2!=nullptr) and (i!=1000)){
        staticArray[i]=head2->exampleObject;
        head2=head2->next;
        i++;
    }
else
    if (head2==nullptr)
        while ((head1!=nullptr) and (i!=1000)){
            staticArray[i]=head1->exampleObject;
            head1=head1->next;
            i++;
        }
```

can be semplified as

```
    while ( head2 && (i < 1000) ){
        staticArray[i++]=head2->exampleObject;
        head2=head2->next;
    }

    while ( head1 && (i < 1000) ){
        staticArray[i++]=head1->exampleObject;
        head1=head1->next;
    }
```

But you're using C++11, so I suggest the use of `std::array`; something like

```
std::array<ExampleObject, 1000> staticArray;
auto i = 0U;
while ( head1 && head2 && i < staticArray.size() ){
    if ( head1->exampleObject.name < head2->exampleObject.name ){
        staticArray[i++] = head1->exampleObject;
        head1            = head1->next;
    }
    else{
        staticArray[i++] = head2->exampleObject;
        head2            = head2->next;
    }
}

while ( head2 && (i < staticArray.size()) ){
        staticArray[i++] = head2->exampleObject;
        head2            = head2->next;
}

while ( head1 && (i < staticArray.size()) ){
        staticArray[i++] = head1->exampleObject;
        head1            = head1->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some portions of your code are duplicated, just break the code in smaller functions. Here is an example how you could do this

```
const int arraySize = 1000;
static ExampleObject staticArray[arraySize];

void mergeIntoArray(ExampleObject *staticArray, int arraySize, Node *firstList, Node *secondList);

int main()
{
    Node* list1 = // ... create and fill list1
    Node* list2 = // ... create and fill list2

    mergeIntoArray(staticArray, arraySize, list1, list2);

    return 0;
}

Node *addToArrayWithCheck(ExampleObject *array, int arraySize, Node *head, int &i);
Node *addToArray(ExampleObject *array, int arraySize, Node *head, int &i);

void mergeIntoArray(ExampleObject *staticArray, int arraySize, Node *head1, Node *head2)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (head1 && head2) {
        if (head1->exampleObject.name < head2->exampleObject.name)
            head1 = addToArray(staticArray, arraySize, head1, i);
        else
            head2 = addToArray(staticArray, arraySize, head2, i);
    }
    while (head1 = addToArrayWithCheck(staticArray, arraySize, head1, i));
    while (head2 = addToArrayWithCheck(staticArray, arraySize, head2, i));
}

Node *addToArrayWithCheck(ExampleObject *array, int arraySize, Node *head, int &i)
{
    if (head == nullptr) return head;
    return addToArray(array, head, i);
}

Node *addToArray(ExampleObject *array, int arraySize, Node *head, int &i)
{
    if (arraySize == i) return nullptr;
    array[i++] = head->exampleObject;
    return head->next;
}
```

Breaking code into functions makes it look more clean and understandable, but it adds a very little performance penalty. In most situations code readability is more important. I am a little rusty on C++ and I don't know in what context you need this merging, therefore there could be flows in my code.